# Configure routing with SNMP

Tags: snmp, cisco, cisco-ios

Is there a way to add routes to, for example, RIP routing table, using snmp requests? Where can I get this scenarios described step-by-step?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not a Cisco guy (just open source). Seems like the RIPv2-MIB or the Cisco extension / equivalent may be what you are looking for. Do you get an snmp response when asking for RIPv2-MIB::rip2 (1.3.6.1.2.1.23)?

Comment: I found RIPv2-MIB in cisco object navigator, but can't find there read-create OID's that looks like a start point to create route.

Comment: No read may be an indication that the MIB isn't supported by the device (but not definitely). Which device are you using? [This section](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_4t/12_4t11/htripmib.html#wp1049437) of this page seems to say what you need to do to enable it. Does that help?

Comment: This (http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en) object navigator just shows the definitions of different MIBs. I have a bunch of cisco devices and try to find a common way to add routes in their tables. It seems like the page you given me describes only monitoring of RIPv2, not adding routes. Also, thank you for delving with me and my bad english.

Comment: Sure, no problem. That page is pretty nice, but I think it just an OID resolver. It doesn't tell you what MIBs/OIDs are supported for which devices. What device are you using, or what MIBs does it support (should be in product doc)? You'll need to know that before you can know if SNMP will do any route configuration.

Comment: I have Cisco routers 2801 and 2960 with iOS 12.4-25g.

Comment: I didn't find the list of MIBs for the 2801, but I found [these](ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/supportlists/cat2960/cat2960-supportlist.html) for the 2960. Nothing in this list popped out at me for having routes, but you might take a look and dig through some of the MIBs.